# XML get values from simplexml_load_string

Tags: php, xml

I have this piece of code that takes my xml and puts it into an array, I did a print_r of it and got this...

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [status] => SUCCESS [items] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [item] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => 1_ ) [id] => 1 [name] => Product 3 [price] => 20.00 [qty] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [option] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [id] => 3_ ) [id] => 3 [name] => Test Fin [price] => 30.00 [qty] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [option] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) ) ) ) [amount] => 50 )
```

I am trying to echo out the amount, but nothing I try is working, I am new to xml and dont really know how to use it. if anyone can put me in the right direction, I would really appropriate it.

I've tried this...

```
echo $xml['amount'];
```

oh and here is my code...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($cartArray);
    if($xml->nodename){
        echo "the node exists";
    }
    $code = $xml->someNode;
    $message = $xml->someOtherNode;
```

Thanks,

- J

PS - XML CODE

```
public function getCartItems() {
    $xml = "<?xml version='1.0'?>\n";
    $xml .= "<cart>\n";
    if(strlen($_SESSION["items"])==0) {
        $xml .= "<status>ERR</status>\n";
        $xml .= "<message>Cart is empty</message>\n";
    }
    else {
        $xml .= "<status>SUCCESS</status>\n";
        $xml .= "<items>\n";
        $total = 0;
        $this->itemArr = unserialize($_SESSION["items"]);
        foreach ($this->itemArr as $item) {
            $xml .= "<item id=\"".$item["id"] . '_' .$item["option"] ."\">\n";
            $xml .= "<id>".$item["id"]."</id>\n";
            $xml .= "<name>".$item["name"]."</name>\n";
            $xml .= "<price>".$item["price"]."</price>\n";
            $xml .= "<qty>".$item["qty"]."</qty>\n";
            $xml .= "<option>".$item["option"]."</option>\n";
            $xml .= "</item>\n";
            $total += ($item["price"]);
        }
        $xml .= "</items>\n";
        $xml .= "<amount>".$total."</amount>\n";
    }
    $xml .= "</cart>\n";
    return $xml;
}
```

Comment: Did you try like echo $xml->amount; ?
what are u getting in var_dump($xml) ?

Comment: $xml->amount works thanks Milap :)

Comment: how about if I want to get all the names, how would I echo that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$xml = "<?xml version='1.0'?>";
    $xml .= "<cart>\n";

        $xml .= "<status>SUCCESS</status>";
        $xml .= "<items>";
            $xml .= "<item ids='10'>";
            $xml .= "<id>20</id>";
            $xml .= "<name>ball</name>";
            $xml .= "<price>$50</price>\n";
            $xml .= "<qty>500</qty>\n";
            $xml .= "<option>color</option>\n";
            $xml .= "</item>\n";
            $xml .= "</items>\n";
            $xml .= "<amount>555</amount>\n";

        $xml .= "</cart>\n";
        $xmls = simplexml_load_string($xml);
        $var = $xmls->items->item;
        print_r($var->name);
 ?>
```

It will return

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => ball
)
```

I think, you didnt get name value because the attribute name of item and element of XML was same. so i changed

```
$xml .= "<item id='10'>";
```

to

```
$xml .= "<item ids='10'>";
```

and its done. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<document>
 <title>PHP</title>
 <from>Milap</from>
 <to>Patel</to>
 <body>
  I love PHP
 </body>
</document>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

print_r($xml);
?>
```

Output :-

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [title] => PHP
    [from] => Milap
    [to] => Patel
    [body] => I love PHP
 )
```

and

```
print_r($xml->from);
```

will return

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => Milap
)
```

Comment: I tried this and print_r($xml->name); and it returned SimpleXMLElement Object ( )

Comment: @user1193385 See my second answer.